# requestAnimationFrame with higher rate than 60 fps

Tags: javascript

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), I have this:

> Be sure to always use the first argument (or some other method for
> getting the current time) to calculate how much the animation will
> progress in a frame, otherwise the animation will run faster on high
> refresh rate screens.

With this, Can I assume that with a 144hz monitor, for instance, I could have `requestAnimationFrame` running faster than 60 fps?

Comment: Can you clarify on what the "elapsed technique" is? Not sure how you can "control" (increase) refresh rate at native code level with sandboxed script.

Comment: Sry, forget about this elapsed technique, it does not apply to `requestAnimationFrame `.

Comment: From the same MDN page, *"The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation."* So yes.

Comment: Nice, didn't see this one! Thank you.

Comment: Just remember JS is browser dependent. Make to to test on different browsers. I also won't be surprised it's OS dependent as well, since browsers rely on the desktop's window management program as well to give them reliable information about the displays.

Comment: And of course, the other reason is that frames may be delayed by intensive processing, *slowing down* the animation if it doesn't use the time rather than number of callbacks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly true.

Here is a simple example to measure:

```js
let i = 0;
const start = Date.now();
const stop = start + 5000;

function raf() {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    const now = Date.now();
    if (now < stop){
      i++;
      raf();
    }else{
      const elapsedSeconds = (now - start) / 1000;
      console.log('Frame rate is: %f fps', i / elapsedSeconds);
    }
  });
}

console.log('Testing frame rate...')
raf();
```

On my machine, it shows 143.7401178670024. And I am using 144HZ monitor.

Comment: I've changed your code, so it seems to work in the snippet editor too... Feel free to rollback if you find an issue with it.

Comment: I have an Asus gl502vm with 120hz monitor, but I get ~60 fps

Comment: @FZs Works perfectly fine in both scenarios, thanks!

Comment: @Leonardo might be your refresh rate set to 60?

Comment: @Leonardo Maybe just quickly search your browser and your OS online? I'm using Ubuntu and non of my browsers like Gnome's window manager. So I don't get an accurate display scaling number through `window.devicePixelRatio`.

Comment: @DanielCheung window 10, google chrome; I guess 120hz steps-in when necessary like when playing games. maybe its generally on 60hz for power-consumption

Comment: On my machine it shows 59.9 FPS, but I am using a 144 Hz monitor. Tried on chrome and firefox.

Comment: @FireFuro99 Same for me, 144 HZ monitor and 60 FPS. But in my case this is expected, integrated video doesn't allow to get more. You can check this in the display settings

Comment: Yeah, did some trying around after seeing your "might be your refresh rate set to 60" comment, and figured it out. My monitor had somehow set itself back to the default settings... Where the framerate is limited to 60..
Set it back to 144 and now it works as expected. Thanks for the help.